# Symfony query - retrive all items of one user

Tags: php, mysql, function, symfony

I wrote a query to return all cards purchased by specific user. I dont know what I am doing wrong. I defined user_id in cards table and added few cards manually too test.

My Service..

```
public function getUserCardAction($userId)
{

    $card = $this->getCardRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->select('c')
        ->where('c.userId = :userId')
        ->setParameter('userId', $userId)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    return $card;
}
```

My Controller..

```
public function getUserCard()
{

    $this->get('card.configuration')->getUserCardAction($this->getUser());

    return $this->success();

}
```

Comment: And what error you get?

Comment: It returns TRUE but no data. I entered to cards with user_id 1 in db.

Comment: show us your entity class

Comment: /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $userId;

Answer (score 0):

You are returning

```
$this->success();
```

What function is that ?

Shouldnt you return the result of your query ? Like :

```
return $this->get('card.configuration')->getUserCardAction($this->getUser());
```

Comment: The controller must return a response (Array(0 => Object(Bundle\Base\Entity\Card), 1 => Object(Bundle\Base\Entity\Card)) given).

Comment: Yes, in Symfony a controller must return a response object. The question is what you expect as a return.
Do you call it via ajax and want a  JsonResponse or do you want to pass the data to the render function for example.
Thats why i asked whats inside your success function. Can you provide that code ?

Comment: You also could get the result directly via doctrine to shorten things up

$this->em->getRepository('App:Cart')->findBy(['userId' => $this->getUser()])

Comment: I am trying to return all cards that are owned by the specific user. (User with ID 1)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get to the solution.

I just edited my Controller.

```
 $card = $this->get('card.configuration')->getUserCardAction($this->getUser());

    return $this->success($card);
```

Comment: Try to add ‘->getUserCardAction($this->getUser()->getId())’